# KQL summarize by count and then filter

Tags: kql

The goal of my query is to see if at any given minute we have more than 500 logs.

I have this line at the end `| summarize count() by bin(env_time, 1m)`, but now I want to know if I can add filtering beyond that to only see rows with more than 500 results. Something along the lines of:

```
| totals = summarize count() by bin(env_time, 1m)
| where totals>500
```

Is there a way to do this correctly in KQL?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 9700 step 1 | extend env_time = ago(20m * rand()));
t
| summarize count() by bin(env_time, 1m)
| where count_ > 500
```

| env_time | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-08T09:54:00Z | 531 |
| 2023-01-08T09:56:00Z | 501 |
| 2023-01-08T09:57:00Z | 501 |
| 2023-01-08T10:00:00Z | 510 |
| 2023-01-08T10:03:00Z | 502 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAzXMywrCMBCF4X2f4iwz4iItiIjoq5TUjjXQmUg6rRf68M1Clwf%2074xsMFwgwTjHMMYvuxx0YETccxLUsITT0XtMxs8yV/DbWHuwLq1F4aLDkFzjBTsU2zsiOldWrZhmkZDLJ25pVnOE7oMuqvvbPWqhEr4enH9RiysO3m%20s6dYCmQAAAA==)

or (with alias for `count()`)

```
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 9700 step 1 | extend env_time = ago(20m * rand()));
t
| summarize rows_per_minute = count() by bin(env_time, 1m)
| where rows_per_minute > 500
```

| env_time | rows_per_minute |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-08T09:51:00Z | 539 |
| 2023-01-08T09:57:00Z | 501 |
| 2023-01-08T10:02:00Z | 516 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XMQQrCMBBG4X1P8S8TcZEKIiJ6lZDasQY6SZlOrEoPb1y4cvkW3xtJoTiDg5LEMMY3GQlpIETcJDNaaMbx4BxmpanmCnoqpR6UHl4jU9VhyGbnGBtU2xtr7anRZsVcmIPUJyQvs59IPMdU9GuuuSQ1Ft0LXUzmd9uiZVvpcif5ZxfsnfsAqKBsVLQAAAA=)